# Maven tests run sequentially (multithreaded tests) for unknown reason

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, completable-future

I have a code that heavily uses `CompletableFuture`, and my colleague has made a few tests.

The tests seem to pass at my machine, but fail at his.
I found the bug (even though the tests pass at my machine), but I want be sure that I fixed it correctly, without bothering my colleague (to run tests).

For some reason, the multi-threaded code in the tests runs sequentially.

I run Maven tests this way:

```
mvn test -Dtest=CompFutTest -DfailIfNoTests=false -DprintSummary=false
```

Comment: what is your question actually?

Comment: My question is do I miss something in the command line?
Any more places (IntelliJ, Maven, computer?) to look at to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maven-surefire-plugin controls concurrent execution.

If you **want** your tests to run concurrently then configure your surefire plugin with one of ...

```
<parallel>methods</parallel>
<parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
```

... depending on whether you want concurrency within each test case or across test cases.

The choice of parallel value (and the related choice of threadCount) and various compatability issues between TestNG, JUnit and the surefire plugin are addressed in more detail in [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).